# AJAX logic not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am new to AJAX and learning it. I am searching a food item in my HTML textbox and trying to communicate with the server to know if the item is available. The respective status of the item should be shown in the div tag below the textbox but it is not showing.

I haven't studied jQuery yet and would like to know the below things:

1. How to get the response from the server in plaintext using AJAX and JavaScript, and display it in the div tag below the textbox (advise the changes to be made in the code).
2. What change should I make in JavaScript code to send the AJAX request in POST method (I know about the changes in PHP code)?

//index.html

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="food.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>The Cheff's Place</h3>
  Enter the food you want to order

  <input type="text" id="userInput" name="input" onkeypress="sendInfo()"></input>

  <div id="underInput"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

//food.js

```
var request;

function sendInfo() {
  var v = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var url = "index.php?food=" + v;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  if (request.readyState == 0 || request.readyState == 4) {
    try {
      request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
      request.open("GET", url, true);
      request.send(null);
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Unable to connect to server");
    }
  }
}

function getInfo() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      var val = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = val;
    }
  }
}
```

//index.php

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  $food = $_GET['food'];
  $foodArray = array("paneer", "butter", "chicken", "tandoori", "dal");
  if (in_array($food, $foodArray))
  {
    echo "We do have " .$food;
  }

  elseif($food == "")
  {
    echo "Kindly enter some food";
  }

  else
  {
    echo "We do not sell " .$food;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Try following the example here. You can get the response after the request comes back in `xhr.responseText` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Comment: I tried but it is not helping.
It would be helpful if you would try the above code at your end and let me know the changes to be made in the code.

Comment: In food.js this condition will never happen since request is not sent at that point. `if (request.readyState == 0 || request.readyState == 4)`  so none of the code is getting executed in there

Comment: I tried writing document,write() after request.send(null) and the code in document,write() was shown on the page.

I also tried document.write() after  if (request.readyState == 4) and it was also executed but when I wrote  document.write() after if (request.status == 200) { the code in write() was not executed.

I guess something is wrong in if (request.status == 200) if possible please advise.

Comment: Kindly advise what change should I make in JavaScript code to send the AJAX request in POST method (I know about the changes in PHP code)

Comment: You can read how to post with xmlhttp here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST

Comment: After if (request.status == 200) { i have written document.write(request.status);
The output is 0.
Is there anything wrong in my php code, why am I getting the output as 0 instead of 200.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. It's working fine. Just replace onkeypress with onkeyup.

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" name="input" onkeyup="sendInfo()"></input>
```

Using JQuery (Assuming you have included jquery file or cdn) :

Include the following snippet in script tag at the end of the body.

```
    $("#userInput").keyup(function(){
        $.get("index.php", { food: $("#userInput").val() })
            .done(function(data) {
                $("#underInput").html(data)
            })
    });
```

Comment: I am not verse with jquery sir, so any help with respect to javascript would be helpful.

Comment: I tried using onkeyup but it is still not working.
I didn't include the jquery code.

It would be helpful if you would try the above code at your end and let me know the changes to be made in the code if not working.

Comment: Kindly advise what change should I make in JavaScript code to send the AJAX request in POST method (I know about the changes in PHP code)

Comment: After if (request.status == 200) { i have written document.write(request.status);
The output is 0.
Is there anything wrong in my php code, why am I getting the output as 0 instead of 200.